Can someone explain why this fix for a NullPointerException works?
My application parses .xml files and transforms them into Kotlin classes. It builds JavaClasses based on XSD files. One of the NonNull properties was null, which was causing an uncaught exception. So I decided to wrap it in a try..catch in order for us to catch it and print additional information. However, I got a NullPointerException on the line where the function was invoked.
Implementation 1 (NPE on function invocation, not caught):
private fun Message.statusInformation(body: StatusBody) = try {
            this.statusInformation //Function marked as @NotNull in generated Javacode
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
            //Logging and throwing a different exception
        }

Implementation 2 (NPE was caught in the handler):
private fun Message.statusInformation(body: StatusBody): StatusInformation = try {
            this.statusInformation //Function marked as @NotNull in generated Javacode
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
            //Logging and throwing a different exception
        }

From the callers perspective the type was still StatusInformation, but the second implementation worked like expected.
Can someone explain why adding the return type to the expression prevented the uncatchable NPE? Or where to find documentation on this, I was unable to find any.

This is a very interesting behaviour. I'm not sure if this constitutes an answer, but Kotlin generates the checkNotNull differently. Without the explicit return type, it is checkNotNull(try { this.statusInformation } catch { ... }). With the explicit return type, it becomes try { checkNotNull(this.statusInformation) } catch { ... }. This explains why you were (not) able to catch the NPE, but doesn't explain much otherwise. The Kotlin/JVM spec is still work in progress, so there likely isn't documentation documenting this.

@Sweeper It helps to understand why there is a difference in behavior. Would you consider this unexpected behavior? Because it might be worth it to flag it with the Kotlin devs in that case (if this is unintended). I'll be happy to send them a message :)

Reporting it is a good idea. I have been trying to find similar issues. This issue might be related...

As far as I understand, null checks should always be present at the boundary between kotlin and java code. It being outside the try block is unexpected to me.

In implementation 1 you don't say the return type explicitly, so Kotlin tries to infer the return type, but this method is like NotNull, so if it returns null, the NullPointerException error occurs before the try -catch and therefore the error was not caught.
In implementation 2 you declare the return type, then Kotlin handles everything within try-catch, which is why it can detect NullPointerException in the catch block

The return type for both methods is the same. Additionally, saving the result intermediately in a val/var without the explicit type also works as expected.
